# Modern style of ComboBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I'm new in WPF and I'm trying to create ComboBox like in the picture

[ComboBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKy2r.png)

I have faced the following problems:

1. Make the arrow "inside" the ComboBox, not to the right.
2. Underline ComboBox items. (I tried to use border, but it overlaps the text of item)

How can these problems be resolved?

Comment: Use styles. Its the fastest and cleanest way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [WpfThemesCollection](https://github.com/StanislawSwierc/WpfThemesCollection), it has a bunch of themes for you to learn how styles and templates work. Then you will be able to build the ComboBox as you'd like it.